# mod rewrite help

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod rewrite to remove and replace part of my url. I am looking to get my urls looking like this.

```
http://domain.com/e813c697e8dd8dc2bbfecb1d20b15783.html
```

instead of

```
http://domain.com/lookup.php?md5=e813c697e8dd8dc2bbfecb1d20b15783
```

lookup.php calls matches the md5 to the database and fetches and forwards you to the correct url.
All I need to do now is rewrite it so that it rewrites from this

```
http://domain.com/lookup.php?md5=e813c697e8dd8dc2bbfecb1d20b15783
```

to this

```
http://domain.com/e813c697e8dd8dc2bbfecb1d20b15783.html
```

I have tried this which works but it makes rewrites from any .html page at root level and makes it display nothing "blank".

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1
```

Can anyone tell me a way to do this so that my regular html pages are not messed up and be able to display these links how I want to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rule is a way too broad. You need to make it more specific to only match md5 hash value -- which is easy:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]{32})\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1 [QSA,L]
```

1. Your pattern for file name is too broad -- it will match any file with letters and digits. md5 hash, on another hand, uses very limited subset of characters (`a-f` only) and digits .. and has to be **32** characters long. This pattern `([a-f0-9]{32})` does the job perfectly.
2. I have also added `L` and `QSA` flags (`QSA` to preserve any existing query string (like, tracking info, for example) and `L` to stop matching any other rules).
3. To further ensure that it does not match any real files which may have name in such format (who knows), add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line before the rule.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is quantify the number of hex digits:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-f]{32})\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1
```

as md5 will always have 32 hex digits.

Comment: You have extra `]` in your pattern. Otherwise: +1

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the naming scheme of your regular html pages. For starters though you could change it to: `RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1`

Which would make any html pages which have a letter not between `a` and `f` work.

If none of your HTML pages have numbers in their names, and if the cost of a page not redirecting outweighs the odds of an md5 hash having no numbers in it. You could check that there is at least one digit in the filename: `RewriteRule ^([a-f]*\d[a-f\d]+)\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1`

Lastely if it is acceptable for you to have urls like `http://domain.com/md5/e813c697e8dd8dc2bbfecb1d20b15783.html` instead you could change it to: `RewriteRule ^md5/([a-f0-9]+)\.html$ /lookup.php?md5=$1` and not have to worry about the fragileness of the other methods.

I'm not sure, but I think you have a `RewriteBase /` somewhere in you .htaccess judging by your example mod_rewrite. If not you might need to add a `/` right after the `^` in whatever RewriteRule you choose to go with.